# Prisma: how to exclude properties from generated types

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, prisma

**EDIT**
there's a hidden danger in hiding fields in the TS definitions: the fields will not be accessible during development with intellisense, but the full object with "hidden" fields can be accidentally sent in a response, potentially exposing sensitive data.

I'm building my app using Prisma to connect to the DB (Next.js app). I'm having some trouble with the auto generated Typescript definitions.

I'm following [the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types#solution) but I can't figure out how to select a subset of fields from `Post`. In their example:

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const userWithPosts = Prisma.validator<Prisma.UserArgs>()({
  include: { posts: true }, // -> how can I exclude some fields from the Post type?
})

type UserWithPosts = Prisma.UserGetPayload<typeof userWithPosts>
```

Imagine `Post` being as follows (simplified):

```
model Post {
  id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt  DateTime   @default(now())
  title      String
  published  Boolean    @default(false)
  author     User       @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId   Int
}
```

I'd like to exclude some of the auto-generated fields from the `Post` type, for example `createdAt`. Basically `user.posts[0]` type will have all the fields except `createdAt`.

One solution could be:

```
const postData = Prisma.validator<Prisma.PostArgs>()({
  select: { id: true, title: true, published: true, authorId: true }
})

type UserWithPosts = Omit<Prisma.UserGetPayload<typeof userWithPosts>, 'posts'> & {
  posts: postData[]
}
```

But I was hoping for something a bit cleaner. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: instead of using `include` use `select` with a nested `select` for `posts`. The problem is that it becomes quite verbose and cumbersome to maintain (every time a field is added on the schema it must be added here as well...)

```
const userWithPosts = Prisma.validator<Prisma.UserArgs>()({
  select: {
    email: true,
    name: true,
    posts: {
      select: {
        id: true,
        title: true,
        published: true,
        authorId: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```